# Apply filter on linking table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

[image]

I've got a classic case of Category <-> Category_Product <-> Product relation.
CategoryDTO class has `Set<ProductDTO>` member that defined as:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "Category_Product",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CAT_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROD_ID")
)
public Set<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}
```

The problem is that I want to have Category->Product relation if and only if the  **Category_Product.ENABLED is '1'**.
I tried to use `@FilterJoinTable` annotation but, as I understand, it works on entities only (not on linking table), so it doesn't help here.
I hope that there is an elegant solution that uses Hibernate built-in features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hibernate filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html) documentation is clear regarding `@FilterJoinTable`:

> When the collection use an association table as a relational
>   representation, you might want to apply the filter condition to the
>   association table itself or to the target entity table. To apply the
>   constraint on the target entity, use the regular `@Filter` annotation.
>   However, if you want to target the association table, use the
>   `@FilterJoinTable` annotation.

So, it should work.