# Apply Dynamic filter on linking table in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, filter

I have two model

Personal Info:- which have Column name such as

```
id
address
Phone no
```

Model B :-

```
id
pi_id(Personal Info Id)
name
remaining balance
```

right now i'm fetching data directly from table and to get data from table i'm using
JoinColumn() Annotation on pi_id and id of table Personal Info

What i want to achieve is i can also apply filter on any field of table Personal Info from the model of Table B only how can i achieve this i have tried This solution
[Apply filter on linking table in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843550/apply-filter-on-linking-table-in-hibernate)

But looks like it only works for fixed value what i want to achieve is dynamic filter like

name is something and phone number is something, how can i achieve this

Comment: As you are using Spring Boot already I would advice to add Spring Boot Data JPA and make use of JPARepository with its auto-generated methods. It would look like a one liner: findByPersonalInfoName or findByPersonalInfoPhoneNo

Comment: I Can't write all the combinations i want to use JPA dynamic filters only there are way to many fields to handle in models